# search a string between property values after mapping to an object using mapster and before executing query

Tags: asp.net, linq, filtering, mapster

how can I apply predicates after projecting to a type with mapster?

so I have this

```cs
public sealed class PRGeneric<T> :  where T : class
{
    public async Task<List<T2>> GetPaginated<T2>(
        Expression<Func<T2, object>>? OrderField,
        bool Descending,
        string Search = "") where T2 : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> query = _db.Set<T>();
        var result = query.ProjectToType<T2>(_mapper.Config).ToList();

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
        {
            var props = typeof(T2).GetProperties();
            foreach (var item in result.ToList())
            {
                bool contained = false;
                foreach (PropertyInfo item2 in item.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    var value = item2.GetValue(item);
                    var valueAsString = Convert.ToString(value);
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString) && valueAsString.Contains(Search))
                    {
                        contained = true;
                    }
                }
                if (contained == false)
                {
                    result.Remove(item);
                }
            }

        }

        if (OrderField != null)
        {
            result = Descending ? result.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(OrderField).ToList() : result.AsQueryable().OrderBy(OrderField).ToList();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

this works perfectly fine but my problem is i want to apply ordering and search before executing my query that means i dont want to use tolist() before applying them somehow like this ...

```cs
var result = query.ProjectToType<T2>(_mapper.Config);

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Search))
{
    var props = typeof(T2).GetProperties();
    foreach (var item in result.ToList())
    {
        bool contained = false;
        foreach (PropertyInfo item2 in item.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            var value = item2.GetValue(item);
            var valueAsString = Convert.ToString(value);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(valueAsString) && valueAsString.Contains(Search))
            {
                contained = true;
            }
        }
        if (contained == false)
        {
            result.Remove(item);
        }
    }

}

if (OrderField != null)
{
    result = Descending ? result.AsQueryable().OrderByDescending(OrderField).ToList() : result.AsQueryable().OrderBy(OrderField).ToList();
}

return result.ToList();
```

I cant use .remove(item) on IQueryable
any ideas how should i do it?